# What is wrong with this NSLocalizableString code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I have this code on Viewcontroller.m, on Xcode:

```
 NSString *language = NSLocalizedString(@"es", @"language");
 NSString *connector = NSLocalizedString(@"de", @"connector to link words");
```

And this one on the "Localizable.strings (English)":

```
"language" = "en";
"connector to link words" = "of";
```

The problem is that with every language I change on the iOs Simulator, I always get the first value, the value of the Viewcontroller.m, instead of get the strings values. 
Does anyone know what is wrong?? Thank you so much!

**UPDATE:**

I have this:

```
NSString *language = NSLocalizedString(@"es", @"language");
NSString *connector = NSLocalizedString(@"de", @"connector to link words");
```

But it still doesn't work!! Why????
It only shows the key values!! In the strings I have:

```
"es" = "en";

"de" = "of";
```

on the english file, and on the spanish file:

```
"es" = "es";
"de" = "de";
```

**SOLUTION:**
I think I have already done everything right, so the problem must to be in the iOs simulator. If anyone can take advantage of that, my solution has been edit the scheme clicking in the image of the project in the superior task bar, and in the tab "Options" (on the Run part) set "Spanish" as my language by default.
Thanks everybody anyway.

Comment: When all else fails, read the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of NSLocalizedString goes like the below.

```
NSString * NSLocalizedString(
  NSString *key,
  NSString *comment
)
```

The `key` should be used in your `.strings` file. The value of the key will be different for different languages .

So when you run the key will be replaced by the value provided in the language `.strings` file you set.

Look at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

syntax is  NSLocalizedString(key, comment)

> And this one on the "Localizable.strings (English)":
>
> "language" = "en";
>   "connector to link words" = "of";
>
> so "language" is the key and "en" is the value

so

```
NSString *language = NSLocalizedString(@"language", @"");
NSString *connector = NSLocalizedString(@"connector to link words",@"");
```